# Compiling OpenSSH client or Dropbear for Android

Tags: ssh, android, openssh, dropbear

I have an interesting problem.

I'd like to use a private SSH key with my Android Terminal Emulator (`jackpal.androidterm`). I'd like to [install the private key in a fairly-secure location](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60760/storing-ssh-private-keys-on-an-android-device/60761#60761) and be able to access the key in a fairly straightforward way. I'd like to do this:

```
ssh theotherserver
```

With a `~/.ssh/config` file looking like this:

```
Host theotherserver
    User mycustomuser
```

And the private key being read from `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

The problem is that Dropbear by default looks in `/data/.ssh` (at least here on CyanogenMod 11) and this folder is meant to be owned by `root`. I've done a `chown` and `chmod` on the directory and its children to be able to use it with the "app user" which is `u0_a100`, and that works, but these permissions are wiped on reboot: so no go.

What I'd really like to do is to simply tell Dropbear via a configuration file that its home lives in `/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/app_HOME/.ssh`, as this directory will be 'for sure' owned by the "app user" and I won't run into any permissions issues. An added benefit is that other users won't be able to read this directory as it is private to the application. (dir permissions is `drwxrwx--x`) Is there a way to configure Dropbear with a configuration file to change the location of its default `.ssh` directory? It would be awesome if it just used `$HOME`, but it's obviously not.

If that is impossible, how can I compile OpenSSH client or Dropbear for Android in a way that would enable me to achieve my (seeming simple) goal?

Comment: first idea. is it possible that you symlink from `/data/.ssh` to `/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/app_HOME/.ssh`. Should Workaround the permission- and locationproblem.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: Welp, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

As @xx4h mentioned in the comments to the question, a solution was to symlink `/data/.ssh` to `/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/app_HOME/.ssh`:

```
# ln -s /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/app_HOME/.ssh /data/.ssh
```

That fixed it and remains in place after a reboot. Export an environment variable to make it easy to modify SSH config:

```
SSH_HOME="/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/app_HOME/.ssh"
```

Either that or just drop another symlink in there.